# How to copy not only binary file into CLion "Build output path"?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I starded default "untitled" project in CLion. Add in project directory "config" with file "tools.conf" in it.

Then I changed default CMakeLists.txt to this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})

install(DIRECTORY config DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
install(PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
```

Now I can type manually in shell:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/me/build .; make; make install
```

And binary with directory both will be in /home/me/build.

But if I set in CLion - File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - CMake - Build output path - /home/me/build and then press "Build" button. It generates directory /home/me/build/Debug and puts only one binary "untitled" in it.

I want CLion copied all project files in its "Build output path". How can I do this?